# Как на C# получить список процессов и запущенных служб Windows?

Tags: c#, windows

Как на C# получить список процессов и служб Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Список служб можно получить через [SeviceController.GetServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Список процессор через [Process.GetProcesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Не уверен на счет получения списка процессов Windows... Вроде, там какой-то нюанс с разрядностью, т.е x64 приложение не видит х32.

Comment: Дополню- что б пример со службами заработал- добавьте ссылки проекта на using System.ServiceProcess и
using System.Management;